# ng-model on radio always stays to true

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to bind radio buttons with `obj.flagX` but the model value doesn't seem to be in sync with the radio button state.

When the page loads, and the radio is untouched. the value of `obj.flagX` is `undefined`. But once I change/select a radio, the corresponding flag value changes and it stays `true` even if I select another radio button after that.

```
<input type="radio" name="fldName" ng-value="true" ng-model="obj.flag1">
<input type="radio" name="fldName" ng-value="true" ng-model="obj.flag2">
```

I am confused if I should or should not use ng-value directive? logically the value `true` is correct but the problem is that how the model value can be reset/removed if the radio is unchecked. Am I doing wrong by using different model keys for different radios?

Answer (score 2):

Value in `<input type="radio">` stays for model value when it's chosen, if you need check/uncheked functionality you need to use `<input type="checkbox">`

Comment: But the UI requirement is to select one option. and I want to be able to set the final value from the selected radio to the model. You mean it isn't possible?

Comment: could you explain what you want to have as a result. Because with js everything is possible :)

Comment: I agree. :) But this looks kinda confusing. I just want to receive the value of selected radio on server.

Comment: I think this doc may help you: [input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Comment: The doc doesn't seem to have any solution for this. It doesn't show how do I uncheck a radio and its corresponding model. Anyway thanks

Comment: radio stands for selecting an item from list, when checkbox is for checking/unchecking. Do you want to have 2 checkboxes and only one or none of them selected every time? or?

Comment: I can't use checkboxes because atleast one option needs to be selected by the user. The form can not proceed without that.

Comment: well, you definitely doing to need javascript here, and I think checkboxes still better choice here. Smthing like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwNypB